# есть другой способ продолжения после ошибки?

Tags: python-3.x

есть другой способ продолжить после ошибки, надо из n извлечь min(n), но если n пустое то ошибка?

```
def startb():
while True:
    try:
        n = str('')
        print("n", n, type(n))
        try:

            b = min(n)

            print("tryb")
        except:

            print("ValueError")
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print("else")

        m = 3
        print("m", m, type(m))
        time.sleep(2)
        if m ==2:
            print(m)
        print("после if")

    except Exception as e:
        print("except1", e)
        time.sleep(1)
```

изначально код такой был

```
def startb():
while True:
    try:
        n = str('')
        b = min(n)
        print("b", b, type(b))
        time.sleep(2)
        дальше ещё что
        ..............

    except Exception as e:
        print("except1", e)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Это вопрос или утверждение?

Comment: вопрос )) трай ексепт елсе както не смотрится, может более компактное решение и получше есть?

Comment: Здесь n всегда равно пустой строке, поэтому половину кода можно вообще убрать.

Comment: о нееет! это пример, если у меня будет пустая строка, там не пустая но бывает и пусто, пытаюсь обойти ошибку и продолжить выполнение кода дальше

Comment: Внешний try не нужен. В нем никаких исключений не случается.